# How to convert the mm/dd/yyyy format into dd-mm-yyyy in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Please tell anybody how to convert the date format 06/12/2012 into 12-06-2012 in mysql select query

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: a MySQL SELECT will return CCYY-MM-DD

Comment: and, isn't it easier and faster to google than to ask here?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(yourSillyDateField, '%d-%m-%Y')
FROM
    yourSillyTable
```